# Spring Batch DB not getting updated

Tags: spring, workflow, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am writing a business logic in Tasklet where i am sending a message to one of the external systemA's Queue and then stopping the job using operator.stop() method(Sometimes response comes very late so i am releasing the system's resource by stopping spring batch job) .

As soon as i receive the reply from the systemA i need to again restart the job from the last completed job .

This is what i have done in tasklet .

```
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepCon, ChunkContext chunkCtx)
            throws Exception {

        JobOperator operator= (JobOperator)ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("jobOperator");

            String msg = "some msg";
    //Sending message to channel created using spring integration.
    messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg).build());
        //Stopping job with the job_exe_id 123
            operator.stop(123);
            ExitStatus es = new ExitStatus("MSG_SENT");
            stepCon.setExitStatus(es);
            return null;

    }
```

The problem that i am facing now is that as soon as the message is sent to systemA's Queue ,in no time i get response from systemA and spring integration's service activator gets called and for some reason the spring batch  DB never get updated as "STOPPED" , instead the DB entry shows status of the job as "STOPPING" and because of this i am not able to restart the job inside the service activator since it is still in "STOPPING" state .

Could anyone please let me know why spring batch DB is not getting updated with the status of "STOPPED" state .

**EDIT-** I have tried stopping the job before the sending the message to SystemA's queue but still SPRING BATCH DB is not getting updated with "STOPEED"  status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time when I get a response from the external system, the `tasklet`'s transaction where I am sending the message was not getting committed.

To solve the above issue I used a step execution listener, I did all the DB updating inside the `tasklet` and inside the "afterstep" execution listener I sent the message to the external client, so by the time flow reaches "afterstep" execution listener , the `tasklet` transaction would have got committed.

Hopefully this will help somebody in need.